# Hdl Designer does not generate hdl file

Tags: designer, hdl

I have a problem with HDL Designer. When I create new project and add block diagram and try to check if it's correct HDL Designer show me this error:
[It does not generate hdl files for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi33Q.png)

It does not create hdl file or something. I created a project few days ago and it works perfectly but when  I create new block diagram into it Hdl designer shows the same error. I have no idea what's wrong. I reinstall hdl designer but it didn't solve problem. Still gives the same error.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Creating the block view does not mean the HDL files are generated.

Instead, after creating the graphical view, you should press the **generate** button to generate the code in the *task* toolbar. It looks like this:
[the **generate** button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4wBz.jpg)

If you do not find the *task* toolbar, then you need to check the option **view** -> **Toolbars** -> **Tasks** to invoke the *task* toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem was that reference for 'Generate Task' was not found. So I added it as follows - Tasks -> Supplied Tasks -> Generate -> OK